# How to designate a generic type as "don't care"?

Tags: generics, rust

I have a trait that designates allowed pin configurations for a microcontroller:

```
pub trait TimChannelsMapping<TIM>: Sized {
    const MAPPING: u8;
}
```

It is used this way:

```
//TIM1
impl<PINMODE1, PINMODE2, PINMODE3, PINMODE4> TimChannelsMapping<TIM1>
    for (
        Option<PA8<Alternate<PINMODE1>>>,
        Option<PA9<Alternate<PINMODE2>>>,
        Option<PA10<Alternate<PINMODE3>>>,
        Option<PA11<Alternate<PINMODE4>>>,
    )
{
}
```

The idea is that I implement only the configurations allowed for the microcontroller.

I don't really care about the `PINMODEx`, and their presence makes the use of this trait complicated, because even for tuple slots whose value is `None`, I have to pass a mode which is quite ugly and complicated:

```
let pins = (Some(a6), Some(a7), Some(b0), None::<PB1<Alternate<OpenDrain>>>);
```

I'd like either to have a designation for "don't care" or a way to give a default value.

Comment: *I don't really care about the `PINMODEx`* — this cannot be true; if you truly didn't need to care about it, you wouldn't need to put it into your struct / trait / impl.

Comment: It's been imposed to me by the type definition of the pins, but I don't want to check it of follow up on it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a default implementation for the `TimChannelsMapping` trait, you can create a default struct (`DefaultTimChannelsMapping`) or implement it for nothing `()`.

```
impl<TIM> TimChannelsMapping<TIM> for () {
    const MAPPING: u8 = 0;
}
```

Or if you want to abstract away the `None`s of your tuple, you can create a `Builder`.

```
pub struct PinBuilder(
    Option<PA8<Alternate<PINMODE1>>>,
    Option<PA9<Alternate<PINMODE2>>>,
    Option<PA10<Alternate<PINMODE3>>>,
    Option<PA11<Alternate<PINMODE4>>>,
);

impl PinBuilder {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self(None, None, None, None)
    }

    pub fn pa8(mut self, pa8: Option<PA8<Alternate<PINMODE1>>>) -> Self {
        self.0 = pa8;
        self
    }

    pub fn build(
        self,
    ) -> (
        Option<PA8<Alternate<PINMODE1>>>,
        Option<PA9<Alternate<PINMODE2>>>,
        Option<PA10<Alternate<PINMODE3>>>,
        Option<PA11<Alternate<PINMODE4>>>,
    ) {
        (self.0, self.1, self.2, self.3)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let pins = PinBuilder::new().pa8(Some(a6)).build();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's an interesting direction, I'll check if I can avoid the bloat created by thing thing for every possible configuration of pins